# How to get direction turn by turn in android

Tags: android

I'm making an Taxi app for android,I'm displaying the route on the map. My map and route works fine, but i want to show direction turn by turn, like turn right, turn left with a point on that turn by clicking that it says now turn left or right, i don't know how to do that, i have searched many times in many different ways, but non match my requirement, i need a working example of direction turn by turn, so that i can run it and study it, it would be a great help.

[image]

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is currently considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please explain **completely and precisely** what your requirements are, what techniques you tried, and what problems you encountered.

Comment: i'm new in android,i don't know how to get direction on each turn, like turn right or left, and want to show it in a textview

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK or Play Services Framework for that. You will need to get this information from someplace else (e.g., a Web service).

Comment: then how i can get direction on turns, there must be some thing that can help

Comment: Have you seen Google Directions API for Android?

Comment: yes still studying it

Comment: don't you have any working code that may help??